# How to find out the request.session sessionid and use it as a variable in Django?

Tags: python, django, session, sessionid, django-sessions

I'm aware that you can get session variables using `request.session['variable_name']`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to grab the session id(key) as a variable in a similar way. Is this documented anywhere? I can't find it.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
request.session.session_key
```

Note the key will only exist if there is a session, no key, no session. You can use this to test if a session exists. If you want to create a session, call create.

Comment: @aehike: `request.session._session_key` as per the answer from @Vinicius

Comment: `request.session.session_key` works fine in Django 1.6.

Comment: ``request.session.session_key`` also works fine in Django 1.7.

Comment: @p1l0t Umm.. You went too far ahead.. That's something to come in future.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: Document here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

Comment: False. `request.session.session_key` resolves to `None` in Django 1.8.

Comment: @Dan Using it without problem in 1.8 `request.session.session_key`.

Comment: I prefer using `request.session._get_or_create_session_key()` because, it can happen that there is just no ID yet.

Comment: Whether this works or not entirely depends on whether the session has been created. See my answer

Comment: Why is the session being accessed like an object when `request.session` is a dictionary-like object?

Answer (score 25):

Django sessions save their key in a cookie. At least its middleware extracts it like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
session_key = request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the session key doesn't exist though.

Answer (score 20):

in Django >= 1.4 use:

```
request.session._session_key
```

Comment: Erm, the main intent of private variables (ones starting with an underscore) is that you should **not** use them.

Comment: @MichałGórny so what's the alternative? if there is none, I don't see how we have a choice...

Comment: The alternative is to write proper code. If django doesn't provide a *public* API to obtain the session key, it simply means you aren't supposed to use that key. I can't tell you more without knowing what exactly you are trying to do but then it's probably a field for separate question.

Answer (score 13):

This will either get you a session ID or create one for you. If you do `dir(request.session)`, you will get many useful methods.

```
['TEST_COOKIE_NAME', 'TEST_COOKIE_VALUE', '__class__', '__contains__',
'__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__',
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__',
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
'__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 
'_get_new_session_key', '_get_or_create_session_key', '_get_session',
'_get_session_key', '_hash', '_session', '_session_key', 'accessed',
'clear', 'create', 'cycle_key', 'decode', 'delete', 'delete_test_cookie',
'encode', 'exists', 'flush', 'get', 'get_expire_at_browser_close',
'get_expiry_age', 'get_expiry_date', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems',
'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'load', 'modified', 'pop', 'save',
'session_key', 'set_expiry', 'set_test_cookie', 'setdefault',
'test_cookie_worked', 'update', 'values']


session_id = request.session._get_or_create_session_key()
```

Answer (score 13):

To reliably get the session key, you need to make sure the session has been created first. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views) mentions a `.create()` session method, which can be used to make sure there's a session key:

```
def my_view(request):
    if not request.session.session_key:
        request.session.create()

    print(request.session.session_key)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
request.COOKIES['sessionid']
```

Answer (score 3):

In Django 1.8:

> request.session.session_key

and

> request.session._session_key

Both work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the session key with [session_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.base_session.AbstractBaseSession.session_key), `_session_key` and `_get_session_key()` in Django Views as shown below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    print(request.session.session_key) # w85oia6b5yqj5n2t6n7lpwuhw7lt7ti2
    print(request.session._session_key) # w85oia6b5yqj5n2t6n7lpwuhw7lt7ti2
    print(request.session._get_session_key()) # w85oia6b5yqj5n2t6n7lpwuhw7lt7ti2
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, you can get the session key with `request.session.session_key`in Django Templates as shown below:

```
{# "templates/index.html #}

{{ request.session.session_key }} {# w85oia6b5yqj5n2t6n7lpwuhw7lt7ti2 #}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can **check in your sessions** too:

```
If "var" in request.session:
       Var = request.session['var']
        Return httpResponse("set")
Else:
       Return httpResponse("there isn't")
```