# Django 1.5 Session Key is None

Tags: django

For some reason, doing `{{ request.session.session_key }}` in the template gives me a `None` value. After some searching, came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526179/in-django-how-can-i-find-out-the-request-session-sessionid-and-use-it-as-a-vari) that mentioned using `request.session._session_id` but using that in the template gives me an error:

> Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores:
>   'request.session._session_key'

My understanding of sessions in Django is that the moment a user loads a page (any page), even if he is anonymous, a session_id is assigned to that particular session. Is my understanding wrong and also, is this where [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526179/in-django-how-can-i-find-out-the-request-session-sessionid-and-use-it-as-a-vari) `[SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST]` is supposed to come in?

I'm using database backend as my session store.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It is still possible to access the session key using `{{ request.session.session_key }}`. However, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) mention that a session will only be created if you've saved/modified the session.

> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session
>   has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been
>   assigned or deleted:

So in my case, the session wasn't being set because I wasn't manipulating it. Using `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` will indeed solve the problem globally. In my use case, I only needed it on a particular view function so it was a simple matter of doing this:

```
if not request.session.get('has_session'):
    request.session['has_session'] = True
```

Comment: i think SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST is more expensive than your solution for only the required view